# Keytool command to generate a .P12 from a .JKS file

Tags: keystore, keytool, pkcs#12

I am trying to generate a .p12 from k .JKS file using the keytool utility provided by JDK.

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mykeystore.jks -destkeystore mykeystore.p12 -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12

However, this command works only with java 1.6 and above. I need to execute this command from a machine where I do not have JDK 1.6 or a higher one. All I have there is a JDK 1.5.

What would be the equivalent of this command if I have to run it from a JDK 1.5 installation.

Please provide some help here.

Thanks,
Maneesh Sharma

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `importkeystore` on Java 5, this feature was introduced from Java 6.

You can refer to the documentation of [Java 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html) and [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html).

If you are looking at importing, you can refer to the [-import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html#importCmd) command (pre Java 6).

Comment: So does that mean I can not do an import of a keystore in one type to a different type using java 1.5 ?